# Angular material sorting table not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material and I generate the tables inside a for loop in the template. I want to add sorting and pagination to these generated tables but what I tried is not working.
I have a list of groups and each group has its items which is a table and I want to be able to sort by `price, quantity, sales`.

```
groups: any[] = [
    {
      name: 'Group 1',
      items: [
        { name: 'Product 1', price: 20, quantity: 33, sales: 11 },
        { name: 'Product 2', price: 10, quantity: 43, sales: 11 },
        { name: 'Product 3', price: 23, quantity: 63, sales: 11 },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Group 2',
      items: [
        { name: 'Product 2', price: 40, quantity: 33, sales: 11 },
        { name: 'Product 4', price: 10, quantity: 143, sales: 211 },
        { name: 'Product 61', price: 63, quantity: 63, sales: 151 },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Group 20',
      items: [
        { name: 'Product 22', price: 40, quantity: 33, sales: 11 },
        { name: 'Product 14', price: 10, quantity: 143, sales: 211 },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

And On HTML I have these:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groups">
  <p>{{ group.name }}</p>
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table [dataSource]="group.items" mat-table matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell>Name</th>
        <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell>{{ element.name }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
        <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header mat-header-cell>Price</th>
        <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell>{{ element.price }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
        <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header mat-header-cell>Quantity</th>
        <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell>{{ element.quantity }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="sales">
        <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header mat-header-cell>Sales</th>
        <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell>{{ element.sales }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" mat-header-row></tr>
      <tr *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" mat-row></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me please I'm stuck?

Check in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mat-table-sort-pgw6lj?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Answer (score 0):

The solution below moves the table HTML script for each sorted Material table into its own component.

As your HTML has a loop containing multiple mat-table components, I recommend trying the following:

Create a component `app-my-sorted-table` that contains the HTML template of your material table and passes in the data trough an input `data` as shown:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groups">
  <p>{{ group.name }}</p>
  <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <app-my-sorted-table [data]="group.items"></app-my-sorted-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your component HTML will look something like this:

```
<table [dataSource]="dataSource" mat-table matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell>Name</th>
    <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell>{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
    <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header mat-header-cell>Price</th>
    <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell>{{ element.price }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
    <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header mat-header-cell>Quantity</th>
    <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell>{{ element.quantity }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="sales">
    <th *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header mat-header-cell>Sales</th>
    <td *matCellDef="let element" mat-cell>{{ element.sales }}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" mat-header-row></tr>
  <tr *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" mat-row></tr>
</table>
```

Your component source including data input will be like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-sorted-table',
  templateUrl: './my-sorted-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-sorted-table.component.css'],
})
export class MySortedTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);

  _data: any[] = [];
  @Input()
  get data(): any[] {
    return this._data;
  }
  set data(value: any[]) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(value);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'price', 'quantity', 'sales'];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('sorting .. ');
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

The above will encapsulate the instance(s) of `MatSort` and the data sources into a shared component re-used within the loop.

To include sorting in the code for the Material table, you will need to include the following imports:

Import the material sort module:

```
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
```

In addition, the following types are required to be imported within each component that uses Material tables and column sorting:

```
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
```

Once the above changes are applied the table columns within each table within the loop will have basic ascending and descending sorting.

Below is the link for the above solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/playground-angular-11-material-eoqltm?file=src/app/my-sorted-table/my-sorted-table.component.ts

Comment: `type 'MatSort' is not assignable to type '(compareFn?: ((a: any, b: any) => number) | undefined) => any[]'.   Type 'MatSort' provides no match for the signature '(compareFn?: ((a: any, b: any) => number) | undefined): any[]'.` I'm getting this error

Comment: I'll have a look.

Comment: were you able to find any solution?

Comment: I will update my answer to include declaring the data source. Then you can try that.

Comment: But with your solution I have to define `sort1 ,sort2 etc` and while on the ng loop I can't know if I will have zero tables or 100. that doesn't work

Comment: I have revised the answer to move the table HTML into a component with a data input and encapsulated sorting and data source. This will allow an indefinite number of tables within your loop.

Comment: I forked and updated your example to Angular/Material 17. I had to change a reference to a non-existing tsconfig.app.json which wasn't there. Just saying. https://stackblitz.com/edit/playground-angular-17-material-nsu3nd